# Set locale in Docker container

Tags: encoding, docker, jboss, locale

I use this image:

```
registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat7-openshift
```

When I run my container I my default locale is:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I need to change this to `ISO-8859-15`
How do I have to do this in my dockerfile?

I first try this at runtime:

```
# localedef -c -i fr_FR -f ISO-8859-15 fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
# export LANG="fr_FR.ISO-8859-15"
```

But when I exit my container and enter it again it's back POSIX.

Update: I tried:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat7-openshift:1.2-12
USER root
RUN localedef -c -i fr_FR -f ISO-8859-15 fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
RUN export LANG="fr_FR.ISO-8859-15"
```

But when I start my container and perform `locale` I get again POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

In you Dockerfile,

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat7-openshift
RUN custom-command_to_change_local.sh
```

Then, you have to build a new image with your custom name.

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

Ok, so, you should use environment and not export in your Dockerfile.
This solution work for me.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat7-openshift:1.2-12

USER root
RUN localedef -c -i fr_FR -f ISO-8859-15 fr_FR.ISO-8859-15

ENV LANG fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:fr  
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.ISO-8859-15
```

I found solution from this article and adapt to redhat OS. http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/

Comment: Check update. I'm not French (but we got some error where 'é' becomes a questionmark in some apps)